# gradle JavaEx- how to set MaxHeapSize?

Tags: java, android, gradle, heap-memory

I want to enlarge my java heap size.

using intellij on mac.

I have tried:

```
task BL_generate_dummy(type: JavaExec) {
    JavaExec.setMaxHeapSize("4096")
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.m.runners.BaselineGeneratorRunner"
}
```

and got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RoutingRegression'.
> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.setMaxHeapSize() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [4096]
  Possible solutions: setMaxHeapSize(java.lang.String), getMaxHeapSize(), setMinHeapSize(java.lang.String), getMinHeapSize()
```

and also

`JavaExec.setMaxHeapSize(4096)`

`JavaExec.maxHeapSize = 4096`

what is the right syntax?

In general if I want to set a Java flag (not to main, but to running process arg). How do i set it in a gradle task?

`task BL_generate_dummy(type: JavaExec) {`

`add '-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m' to the java flags`

Comment: operating system? Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: using intellij on mac.

Comment: why do you need to do it in the gradle task ? Isn't enough to change the vmoptions ?

Comment: I want to run it using a continues integration tool "jenkins"

Comment: Put it in your gradle.properties

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Think the `JavaExec.set` is superfluous.
Do

```
task BL_generate_dummy(type: JavaExec) {
    maxHeapSize = "4096"
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.m.runners.BaselineGeneratorRunner"
}
```

Btw in the current Gradle version (7.x) this will yield some deprecation warning . With Kotlin, change the `mainClass` from

```
main = "com.m.runners.BaselineGeneratorRunner"
```

to

```
mainClass.set("com.m.runners.BaselineGeneratorRunner")
```